# Contour integral with branch point

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, branch-cuts

As preparation for my exam I "invented" the following problem as an exercise to see whether I understand how to work with branch points.

$f(z) = \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2+1} (z^2 +a^2)}$

The goal is to calculate $\int_0^{\infty} f(z) dz$.

I made the following conventions (see figure) for my branches.

$\theta_1 \in [-\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$
$\theta_2 \in [\pi/2, 5\pi/2)$
(let $I_i$ be be the integral on contour $C_i$)
I'm able to calculate that (using my conventions)

$I_1=I_5$

$I_2=-I_4$

$I_6 = 0$

But I'm unsure what $I_3$ is equal to.

My question is: How do I calculate $I_3$?

**Update 1**
My difficulty lies in the fact that $theta_2$ is going to "jump" if I would just integrate in a circle with radius going to zero. Should I maybe do 2 semi-circles? So that I can choose the right value for $theta_2$?
D[image: Problem description]

Comment: Congratulations for inventing your own problems for you to exercise.

Comment: Not every contour integral will necessarily have a reasonable solution. This is the problem with just "inventing" a contour integral. You should also reconsider the $I_2 = - I_4$ thing, because of the branch cut.

Comment: I used maple to check whether a reasonably simple solution exists.

Comment: Regardless of the chosen branches, $I_3$ tends to $0$ when the radius of the circular arc around the branch point tends to $0$. The integrand can be estimated by $\frac{K}{\sqrt{\rho}}$, and the length of the arc is $\leqslant C\cdot \rho$.

Comment: And what Simon says, "in the limit", since you go round the branch point, the integrand on $C_4$ is the negative of the integrand on $C_2$, and due to the orientation, you get $I_2 = I_4$ (in the limit).

Comment: Ah. I made a mistake indeed. When I take $I_2 = I_4$ I get what I expected (cheating a bit with maple now because it was too hard by hand). At least I'm sure now that I understand how to work with branch points. Thanks

Comment: @daniel-fischer  I started wondering. With the chosen conventions isn't there a branch cut on the positive imaginary axis that cuts my contour?

Comment: I had the impression your branch-cut was the segment $[-i,i]$. If you cut from $i$ to "$i\cdot\infty$" and from "$-i\cdot\infty$" to $-i$, your contour passes through the cut, and you can't use that.

Comment: @daniel-fischer I have chosen my contour to be [-i, i]. But I thought that my the ranges I chose for theta define the branch cut. I probably misunderstand something. Does this mean that I can choose the branch cut and the ranges for the two theta's independently?

Comment: I have to admit that I completely ignored the $\theta_i$, since I don't understand what they are supposed to mean.

Comment: @DanielFischer I defined  $z-1 = |z-1| \exp(i\theta_1)$